# python kivy async storage

Tags: python, storage, kivy

I use Synchronous JsonStorage for my app and want to switch to Asynchronous.

My sync call was:

```
store.exists(store_index)
```

My not working async call is:

```
def callback_function(store,key,result):
    print "exists:",result

store.exists(store_index, callback=callback_function)
```

this async call raises the following Exception:

```
store.exists(key=store_index,callback=callback_function)
TypeError: exists() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'
```

I've also tried this:

```
store.async_exists(store_index, callback=callback_function)
```

But this raised:

```
File "main.py", line 199, in __init__  store.async_exists(key=store_index,callback=colorButtonCallback)
File "/home/mike/Dokumente/py-spielwiese/venv/local/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/kivy/storage/__init__.py", line 152, in async_existskey=key, callback=callback)
TypeError: _schedule() got multiple values for keyword argument 'callback'
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Kivy. Your last attempt was pretty much correct (equivalent to the code in @Anzel's answer, though @Anzel's code is a better way to write the same thing). But in the end you will still get the error thrown from `_schedule`. I've just [submitted a PR](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/2815) to fix this in kivy-dev.

Answer (score 1):

`async_exists` takes callback as arguments, then the key so try changing to:

```
store.async_exists(callback_function, store_index)
```

You can read [async_exists](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.storage.html#kivy.storage.AbstractStore.async_exists) to see the details.

Hope this helps.